# Removing double border in top menu Prestashop

Tags: css, menu, navigation, border, prestashop

I am currently building a simple prestashop webshop for some products I sell. I like PrestaShop's default bootstrap theme and there are just some minor things i'd like to adjust.

One of them is the top menu. I already changed the colors, font and added a top border but there is one thing still bugging me and i can seem to remove it!

It is the line underneath the menu items, as shown in the picture attached: [image]

I am editting the superfish-modified.css file found in the modules --> blocktopmenu --> css folder.

All other changes I wanted to implement were also done via that very same CSS.

The (already somewhat modified) CSS file can be found here:
http://lutijn.nl/superfish-modified.css

Comment: Remove this rule `border-bottom: 2px .. ..` in `.sf-menu > li > a {}`

Answer (score 0):

you declare this with your css:

```
.sf-menu > li > a {
    font: 600 18px/22px "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #484848;
    display: block;
    padding: 17px 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e9e9e9; }
```

just remove the `border-bottom` set it to `none`

Comment: Thank you very much mr Basco, this helped a lot! Fixed within 1min! :)